# How can I change date and time format in a CSV File from dd-mm-yyyy & hh:mm:ss to mm/dd/yyyy & hh:mm using Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm getting a date & time result from an API in the format dd-mm-yyyy & hh-mm-ss. I want to convert this to an mm-dd-yyyy format in Python, what's the easiest/quickest way?

I have tried using strftime. However, I could not get it.

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried?

Comment: How about adding some code what you have tried so far? This is a pretty basic problem which you can read in the doc of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your old times to datetime objects, which can then be reformatted into the new format.

```py
>>> def format_timestamps(timestamps, old_format="%d-%m-%Y & %H-%M-%S", new_format="%m/%d/%Y & %H:%M"):
...     new_timestamps = []
...     for timestamp in timestamps:
...        old_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, old_format)
...        new_datetime = old_datetime.strftime(new_format)
...        new_timestamps.append(new_datetime)
...    return new_timestamps
...
>>> format_timestamps(['31-03-2022 & 12-19-23'])
['03/31/2022 & 12:19']
```